# Get distinct values of Queryset by field

Tags: django, field, distinct, django-queryset

I've got this model:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    timestamp  = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField(editable=False)
```

If a user visits multiple times in one day, ***how can I filter for unique rows based on the ip field?*** (I want the unique visits for today)

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
yesterday = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

visits = Visit.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(yesterday, today)) #.something?
```

**EDIT:**

I see that I can use:

```
Visit.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(yesterday, today)).values('ip_address')
```

to get a ValuesQuerySet of just the ip fields. Now my QuerySet looks like this:

```
[{'ip_address': u'127.0.0.1'}, {'ip_address': u'127.0.0.1'}, {'ip_address':
 u'127.0.0.1'}, {'ip_address': u'127.0.0.1'}, {'ip_address': u'127.0.0.1'}]
```

**How do I filter this for uniqueness without evaluating the QuerySet and taking the db hit?**

```
# Hope it's something like this...
values.distinct().count()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select distinct values from a table field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466496/select-distinct-values-from-a-table-field)

Comment: @MarkMikofski is not duplicate, the question here is about Django not about plain SQL

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What you want is:

```
Visit.objects.filter(stuff).values("ip_address").annotate(n=models.Count("pk"))
```

What this does is get all ip_addresses and then it gets the count of primary keys (aka number of rows) for each ip address.

Comment: I don't think I'm totally understanding annotate. As you wrote it, my ValuesQuerySet now has "n":1 appended to each entry. I'm not sure what that's telling me?

Comment: The problem is probably Meta.ordering - try this `Visit.objects.filter(stuff).order_by().values("ip_address").annotate(n=models.Count("pk"))`

Comment: @Greg Thank you! I new that the `ordering` and `order_by()` causes issues with `distinct` but I didn't know how to solve it - although it is in the QuerySet API docs under [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) "_If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call `order_by()` with no parameters._"

Comment: What is `pk` in this case?

Comment: `pk` - primary key. Unique identifier for each record.

Answer (score 36):

With Alex Answer I also have the n:1 for each item. Even with a distinct() clause.

It's weird because this is returning the good numbers of items :

```
Visit.objects.filter(stuff).values("ip_address").distinct().count()
```

But when I iterate over "Visit.objects.filter(stuff).values("ip_address").distinct()" I got much more items and some duplicates...

**EDIT :**

The filter clause was causing me troubles. I was filtering with another table field and a SQL JOIN was made that was breaking the distinct stuff.
I used this hint to see the query that was really used :

```
q=Visit.objects.filter(myothertable__field=x).values("ip_address").distinct().count()
print q.query
```

I then reverted the class on witch I was making the query and the filter to have a join that doesn't rely on any "Visit" id.

hope this helps

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: it was a kind of complement to the Alex answer. I tried it, had the same problem than vfxcode, and then I found why. So I thought I should share my findings.  3 years later, I admit my answer was a bit messy and I understand why you ask this ;)

Answer (score 8):

The question is different from what the title suggests. If you want set-like behavior from the database, you need something like this.

```
x = Visit.objects.all().values_list('ip_address', flat=True).distinct()
```

It should give you something like this for `x`.

```
[1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5, ...]
```

Where

```
len(x) == len(set(x))
```

Returns `True`