# How to generate unique results in django queryset?

Tags: django, view, django-queryset

I'm retriving a set of objects in django view using following query:

```
query=list(channel.objects.order_by('-points')[:10])
shuffle(query)
query2=list(ChannelPost.objects.annotate(num_images=Count('channelpostmedia')).filter(num_images__gt=0).order_by('-user_like').distinct()[:6])
query4=list(CommunityPost.objects.distinct().annotate(num_images=Count('communitypostmedia')).filter(num_images__gt=0).order_by('-user_like')[:16])
query3=list(Communities.objects.distinct().order_by('-points')[:5])
query5=list(channel.objects.distinct().order_by('-chaneldate')[:9])
shuffle(query2)
shuffle(query3)
shuffle(query4)
shuffle(query5)
query6=list(post.objects.order_by('-DatePosted'))
```

The main problem with the queryset is the fact that the result always contain duplicate objects which is undesirable.

**Edit 1** : My question is different from the one suggested with. i'm filtering on the number of images model that a post model can have using annotate , hence, it's not possible to apply the same solution here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get distinct values of Queryset by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432673/get-distinct-values-of-queryset-by-field)

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Check my edit and don't downvote if you can't see it's different when it's clearly a lot more different