# Python 3 Django Rest Framework - how to add a custom manager to this M-1-M model structure?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have these models:

- Organisation
- Student
- Course
- Enrollment

A Student belongs to an Organisation

A Student can enrol on 1 or more courses

So an Enrollment record basically consists of a given Course and a given Student

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

class Organisation(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Student(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  organisation = models.ForeignKey(to=Organisation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.email

class Course(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = models.Manager()
  language = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  level = models.CharField(max_length=2)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.language + ' ' + self.level

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ("language", "level")

class EnrollmentManager(models.Manager):
  def org_students_enrolled(self, organisation):
    return self.filter(student__organisation__name=organisation).all()

class Enrollment(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = EnrollmentManager()
  course = models.ForeignKey(to=Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False, related_name='enrollments')
  student = models.ForeignKey(to=Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False, related_name='enrollments')
  enrolled = models.DateTimeField()
  last_booking = models.DateTimeField()
  credits_total = models.SmallIntegerField(default=10)
  credits_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Notice the custom EnrollmentManager that allows me to find all students who are enrolled from a given organisation.

How can I add a custom Manager to retrieve all the courses from a given organisation whose students are enrolled?

**What I have tried**

I thought to create a CourseManager and somehow query/filter from that side of the relationship:

```
class CourseManager(models.Manager):
  def org_courses_enrolled(self, organisation):
    return self.filter(enrollment__student__organisation__name=organisation).all()
```

This works, but it gives me the same 100 enrollment records :(

What I am trying to get is:
based on a given organisation
find all students who are enrolled
and then (DISTINCT?) to get the list of enrolled courses for that org

**This is the view:**

```
class OrganisationCoursesView(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
  serializer_class = CourseSerializer
  queryset = Course.objects.get_courses(1)
```

**and the url:**

```
# The below should allow: /api/v1/organisations/1/courses/
router.register('api/v1/organisations/(?P<organisation_pk>\d+)/courses', OrganisationCoursesView, 'organisation courses')
```

**UPDATE 1**

Based on the answer from h1dd3n I tried this next:

```
class CourseManager(models.Manager):

  def get_queryset(self):
     return super(CourseManager, self).get_queryset()

  def get_courses(self, organisation):
    return self.get_queryset().filter(student__organisation_id=organisation)
```

but that throws an error (as I expected it would):

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'student' into field. Choices are:
>   courses, created, id, language, level, modified, progress

**UPDATE 2 - getting closer!**

Ok with help from @AKX's comments:

```
class CourseManager(models.Manager):

  def get_queryset(self):
     return super(CourseManager, self).get_queryset()

  def get_courses(self, organisation):
    return self.get_queryset().filter(courses__student__organisation_id=organisation)
```

now DOES return courses, but it returns a copy for each enrolled student. So now I need to group them so each record only appears one time...

Comment: As an aside, since `Organisation.name` isn't unique, using `organisation__name` might return unexpected results if there are multiple organizations with the same name.

Comment: Good spot thanks, I have since changed it to use the id instead

Comment: Does `filter(enrollment_set__student__organisation_id=organisation)` work, by any chance?

Comment: No - Cannot resolve keyword 'enrollment_set' :( Note that the foreign key for a Course is defined in Enrollment (as is the Student foreign key)

Comment: They'd still have reverse relations, á la https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: "You can override the FOO_set name by setting the related_name parameter in the ForeignKey definition" -> I did that locally but forgot to update the question, which I will now do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change `self.filter` to `self.get_queryset().filter()` or make a seperate method in the `manager`.

```
  def get_queryset(self):
     return super(CourseManager, self).get_queryset()
```

In manager create a function

```
  def get_courses(self,organisation): 
     return self.get_queryset.filter(student__oraganisation=organisation)
```

This should return the `students` and you don't need to call `.all()` - the filtered `qs` either way returns you all the objects that it finds.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
class CourseManager(models.Manager):

  def get_queryset(self):
     return super(CourseManager, self).get_queryset()

  def get_courses(self, organisation):
    return self.get_queryset().filter( \
      enrollments__student__organisation_id=organisation).distinct()
```

**UPDATE 2**

You can try and play around with `from django.db.models import Q` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

or with `annotate` based on this answer [Get distinct values of Queryset by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432673/get-distinct-values-of-queryset-by-field) where you filter out each student so it would appear once.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this doesn't quite get there. The "get_courses" returns students. So I have to use the StudentSerializer. I get 100 students (100 enrollments) showing, not just the 8 courses that 100 students have enrolled on. Somewhere/somehow I need to group enrollments by course id, I think

Comment: The Edit gets there ;)