# Exclude fields with the same value using Django querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset

In my project, I have Articles and User Responses that have the same value "title". I only want to find the first Articles, because other object have the same "title", these are the users' answers. How can I exclude objects from queryset have the same "title" parameter.

I try this:

```
q1 = Article.objects.order_by().values('title').distinct()
```

*works good but it returns something like a list.

Well, I tried to convert it to query:

```
q2 = Article.objects.filter(title__in=q1).distinct()
```

*But it causes it to return all Repeat-Topic Articles again.

How to exclude objects from queryset that have the same title without changing them to a list?

Comment: is that what you want ?? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466496/select-distinct-values-from-a-table-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466496/select-distinct-values-from-a-table-field)

Comment: This topic is what I'm using to create my query, but it turns objects into a list. I need a queryset with objects.

Comment: @MaddieGraham, try this: `Article.objects.filter(title__in=q1).order_by('title').distinct('title')`

Comment: In my situation it returns: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Answer (score 2):

On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments `(*fields)` in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply.

If it is your's case then the following must be work:

```
Article.objects.filter(title__in=q1).order_by('title').distinct('title')
```

Comment: But, what if I use sqlite?

Comment: @MaddieGraham note : you shouldn't use sqlite in productive server

Comment: @MaddieGraham, maybe something like this: `pks = queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('title').distinct('title'); Article.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)`